# How to kill a thread from another thread in vala

Tags: multithreading, vala

I have a main thread which creates another thread to perform some job.
main thread has a reference to that thread. How do I kill that thread forcefully some time later, even if thread is still operating. I cant find a proper function call that does that.

any help would be appreciable.

The original problem that I want to solve is I created a thread a thread to perform a CPU bound operation that may take 1 second to complete or may be 10 hours. I cant predict how much time it is going to take. If it is taking too much time, I want it to gracefully abandon the job when/ if I want. can I somehow communicate this message to that thread??

Comment: Why do you want to kill the thread? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I edited the problem statement to explain what I want to do

Comment: Appart from leaking memory, you are leaving a lot of data in unknown state. that is hardly ever a good idea. Signal the thread to stop, and have check for the stop request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a GLib.Thread, you can't.  Even if you could, you probably wouldn't want to, since you would likely end up leaking a significant amount of memory.

What you're supposed to do is request that the thread kill itself.  Generally this is done by using a variable to indicate whether or not it has been requested that the operation stop at the earliest opportunity.  GLib.Cancellable is designed for this purpose, and it integrates with the I/O operations in GIO.

Example:

```
private static int main (string[] args) {
  GLib.Cancellable cancellable = new GLib.Cancellable ();
  new GLib.Thread<int> (null, () => {
      try {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++ ) {
          cancellable.set_error_if_cancelled ();
          GLib.debug ("%d", i);
          GLib.Thread.usleep ((ulong) GLib.TimeSpan.MILLISECOND * 100);
        }

        return 0;
      } catch ( GLib.Error e ) {
        GLib.warning (e.message);
        return -1;
      }
    });

  GLib.Thread.usleep ((ulong) GLib.TimeSpan.SECOND);
  cancellable.cancel ();

  /* Make sure the thread has some time to cancel.  In an application
   * with a UI you probably wouldn't need to do this artificially,
   * since the entire application probably wouldn't exit immediately
   * after cancelling the thread (otherwise why bother cancelling the
   * thread?  Just exit the program) */
  GLib.Thread.usleep ((ulong) GLib.TimeSpan.MILLISECOND * 150);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: here we have to check cancellable.set_error_if_cancelled () in every loop to check if it is already cancelled, can I do something just at the start of the new thread that makes sure it gets terminated when cancelled, because the job that new Thread is performing doesn't have this type of simple loops where I can check it.. I cant check for this condition simply after each meaningful block of code.

Comment: No.  Why can't you check it  after each meaningful block of code?  You just pass the cancellable to any methods you call from the thread callback and have them throw exceptions.  Then all it is is an occasional cancellable.set_error_if_cancelled() invocation, which isn't terribly difficult.

Comment: Perhaps you're asking the wrong question.  Instead of asking how to kill a thread (with glib threads, like I said, you can't), maybe you should be asking how to make a long-running CPU-intensive operation, for which you can't (or won't) modify the code, cancellable...  In which case the answer would be to use a process, not a thread.